# Regex to match mixed case words

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex which will match any word consisting of 8 characters and these characters should belong to the charset: [A-Za-z0-9].

However, they should consist of at least one character from each of the 3 charsets (uppercase, lowercase and digits).

This is the regex I am using:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$
```

however, this will match examples like:

```
09823983
language
mainMenu
```

but I want to match words like:

uXk3mHy9

how can I do this using a regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use three `look-ahead`s in front of your regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: you don't need the trailing `.*` on your look aheads

Comment: What does (?= ... ) mean?

Comment: @gosukiwi It is regex syntax for [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it all in one regex.  Regexes are not a magic toolbox from which all solutions must come.

Check for three different conditions rather than cramming them all into one regex.  In Perl this would be:

```
$ok = ( $s =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$/ && $s =~ /[a-z]/ && $s =~ /[A-Z]/ && $s =~ /[0-9]/ );
```

It is far clearer what your intent is.