# Regular expression for password validation with length as 8 and alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to match mixed case words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410634/regex-to-match-mixed-case-words)

Hello I'm working on a class project for a CIS Class. I need help writing a regular expression that can check a password. The requirements for the password is it must be 8 characters long and must contain one upper and one lowercase letter and at least one number. Thanks for the help.  Example: Pasword1

heres what I have so far
`[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}`

Comment: Paste what you have done so far, so people can help you on your own snippet

Comment: Lookaheads will be of big help, if you're allowed to use them.

Comment: What I would suggest is exploding the password, sorting the elements of the resulting array and imploding them back together.  Then work on a regex that will satisfy your constraints knowing the characters in a sorted order.

Comment: @sberry I'm pretty sure using `explode();` and `implode();` is adding extra efforts; there's already functions to search for capital letters, symbols and information on the strings length

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$/ should work better to validate only passwords containing 8 alphanums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
$password = "Pasword1";
$pattern = '/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $password))
{
    echo "Good password!";
}
else
{
    echo "Bad password";
}
```

Comment: only problem is stuff like this "password" works. I need it to have 8 characters at least one upper case and one lower case and at least 1 number. Example: Pasword1

Comment: @mvmrocks: Did you try it? Because [looks all right to me](http://rubular.com/r/0OGlnfzNqO). The only possible problem is if you want to disallow 9-or-more-character passwords, in which case you just drop the comma near the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do positive lookahead `(?=(regex))` in order to do this.  If you need exactly 8 characters and you are allowed any type of characters other than need 1 each of digit, upper and lower case letter, then you can use this:

```
$pattern = '/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8}$/';
```

If you need 8 or more characters than simply modify to this:

```
$pattern = '/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$/';
```